Black screen every 30 seconds when using my dual boot Ubuntu
I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my PC recently as a dual boot alongside Windows 11. When I boot Ubuntu my screen goes black every 15-30 seconds and I have no control. Sometimes the screen lights up again as if nothing had changed and I can type a few things, but soon after that it goes black again.
For context, my computer is a Samsung Galaxy Book2. It doesn't seem to respond to any keyboard input when on the black screen. I think this might be due to the graphics driver. I have Intel Iris Xe graphics, and I don't know where to start to debug this.
I followed the instructions of this other Ask Ubuntu question which seemed similar to my case. It didn't solve my problem, but now Ubuntu stopped doing the black screen and seems to just go in sleep mode every 15 seconds and I have to press Enter to bring it back.
I think the problem is coming from graphics drivers. I found a temporary solution by adding nomodeset when using a Ctrl+e on the boot start page. With that my dual boot worked fine until the next time I used it and the problem came back. I followed some steps to change the settings of grub to maintain this solution, but it didn't work.

it could be power saver settings does it happen while you recently did activity or during use? if only while idle it might be the power saver mode search for power mode in settings and change the settings. i'm in ubuntu 24.04 and i was able to find those settings for that there.

@williamsoennichsen no, it shuts down even when I am using it so I don't think this is related to power settings.
